# Displaying Posts by Tag - Ruby on Rails Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails blog coming along quite nicely. However, I cannot seem to get my tagged articles to show up within their own page (for example, I'd like ONLY the articles tagged Arts & Entertainment to show up when that link is clicked).

I have a column in my scaffold model entitled tags. It takes a string. So

1) How do I go about accessing ONLY a specific tag? I tried something like the following:

```
def self.sports
    find(:all, :tags => 'gainmuscle')
end
```

to no avail.

2) How do I get them to show up in the view?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably define a method inside your controller something similar to this :

```
def self.tagged_with
  @articles = Article.tagged(params[:tag]).paginate(default_paginate_options)
end
```

Here `tagged` is a `namedscope`. you can neglect that but the action generates all the articles which are tagged with the tag selected as `:param`. Tag is an attribute of the model Article in this case.

Comment: So how would I get this to display on the view (for example, the Sports Article view, given the articles in that view are all tagged sports (which was a user inputed string).

Comment: @TopChef :  get the user input using :params and then in the controller write a method similar to this to get all the articles which has been tagged to the tag the user has given.

Answer (score 1):

1) here you could use the scope in the model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_tag, lambda{|tag| where(:tag => tag)}

  ...
end
```

And then in controller:

```
  @collection = YourModel.by_tag("gainmuscle")
```

2) I would say the best way is to create a partial with html code for 1 single post, and then render it this way:

```
  render :partial => 'post', :collection => @collection
```

(You can check partials usage here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials)

Comment: I think OP is still on rails 2.x - the 'scope' method was introduced in 3.0 I reckon (namedscope before).

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention another approach; there are quite a few gems to deal with this exact purpose. 
[This](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging.html) might be interesting, and personally I can vote for acts_as_taggable_on. This gives you quite a lot of options which might come in handy later on as well.